# Outlook Quick Steps - close email after selecting "Done"

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way for Outlook 2010 to close the currently opened-email (if it's in its own window) after I select "Done" from the Quick Steps item in the ribbon?

I have investigated the Quick Step actions but I can't see anything applicable.

I understand that the "Done" option is available even in the full Outlook window, so closing the current window wouldn't be appropriate here, but it'd be good if it could close it if the email was opened in a new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having kept coming to this post from 2011 I was finally able to answer the question on how to close an e-mail using the quick steps.

Use the 'move' function and move the e-mail to the same folder as it is currently in. This caused the e-mail to close.

Thanks
Greg

Comment: Yep, this works *if* you edit the Move rule and add a `Mark as Complete` action